# With double-checked locking, does a put to a volatile ConcurrentHashMap have happens-before guarantee?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, concurrenthashmap, happens-before

So far, I have used double-checked locking as follows:

```
class Example {
  static Object o;
  volatile static boolean setupDone;

  private Example() { /* private constructor */ }

  getInstance() {
    if(!setupDone) {
      synchronized(Example.class) {
        if(/*still*/ !setupDone) {
          o = new String("typically a more complicated operation"); 
          setupDone = true;
        }        
      }
    }
    return o;
  }
}// end of class
```

Now, because we have groups of threads that all share this class, we changed the `boolean` to a `ConcurrentHashMap` as follows:

```
class Example {
  static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> o = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
  static volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean> setupsDone = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>();

  private Example() { /* private constructor */ }

  getInstance(String groupId) {
    if (!setupsDone.containsKey(groupId)) {
      setupsDone.put(groupId, false);
    }
    if(!setupsDone.get(groupId)) {
      synchronized(Example.class) {
        if(/*still*/ !setupsDone.get(groupId)) {
          o.put(groupId, new String("typically a more complicated operation")); 
          setupsDone.put(groupId, true); // will this still maintain happens-before?
        }        
      }
    }
    return o.get(groupId);
  }
}// end of class
```

My question now is: If I declare a standard `Object` as `volatile`, I will only get a happens-before relationship established when I read or write its reference. Therefore writing an element within that Object (if it is e.g. a standard `HashMap`, performing a `put()` operation on it) will **not** establish such a relationship. ***Is that correct?*** (What about reading an element; wouldn't that require to read the reference as well and thus establish the relationship?)

Now, with using a volatile ConcurrentHashMap, ***will writing an element*** to it ***establish the happens-before relationship, i.e. will the above still work***?

<sub>**Update: The reason for this question and why double-checked locking is important:**
What we actually set up (instead of an Object) is a `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager`, to which we pass some settings, and which we then pass into an `HttpClient`, that we set up, too, and that we return. We have up to 10 groups of up to 100 threads each, and we use double-checked locking as we don't want to block each of them whenever they need to acquire their group's `HttpClient`, as the whole setup will be used to help with performance testing. Because of an awkward design and an odd platform we run this on we cannot just pass objects in from outside, so we hope to somehow make this setup work. (I realise the reason for the question is a bit specific, but I hope the question itself is interesting enough: ***Is there a way to get that `ConcurrentHashMap` to use "volatile behaviour", i.e. establish a happens-before relationship, as the `volatile boolean` did, when performing a `put()` on the `ConcurrentHashMap`?*** ;)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. volatile protects only that object reference, but nothing else.

No, putting an element to a `volatile` HashMap will not create a happens-before relationship, not even with a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Actually `ConcurrentHashMap` does not hold lock for read operations (e.g. `containsKey()`). See [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) Javadoc.

**Update**:

Reflecting your updated question: you have to synchronize on the object you put into the CHM. I recommend to use a **container object** instead of directly storing the `Object` in the map:

```
public class ObjectContainer {
    volatile boolean isSetupDone = false;
    Object o;
}

static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ObjectContainer> containers = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ObjectContainer>();

public Object getInstance(String groupId) {
  ObjectContainer oc = containers.get(groupId);
  if (oc == null) {
    // it's enough to sync on the map, don't need the whole class
    synchronized(containers) {
      // double-check not to overwrite the created object
      if (!containers.containsKey(groupId))
        oc = new ObjectContainer();
        containers.put(groupId, oc);
      } else {
        // if another thread already created, then use that
        oc = containers.get(groupId);
      }
    } // leave the class-level sync block
  }

  // here we have a valid ObjectContainer, but may not have been initialized

  // same doublechecking for object initialization
  if(!oc.isSetupDone) {
    // now syncing on the ObjectContainer only
    synchronized(oc) {
      if(!oc.isSetupDone) {
        oc.o = new String("typically a more complicated operation"));
        oc.isSetupDone = true;
      }        
    }
  }
  return oc.o;
}
```

Note, that at *creation*, at most one thread may create `ObjectContainer`. But at *initialization* each groups may be initialized in parallel (but at most 1 thread per group).

It may also happen that `Thread T1` will create the ObjectContainer, but `Thread T2` will initialize it.

Yes, it is worth to keep the `ConcurrentHashMap`, because the map reads and writes will happen at the same time. But `volatile` is not required, since the map object itself will not change.

The sad thing is that the double-check does not always work, since the compiler may create a bytecode where it is reusing the result of `containers.get(groupId)` (that's not the case with the volatile isSetupDone). That's why I had to use `containsKey` for the double-checking.

Comment: Hi GaborSch, Thank you for your suggestion; that looks really great. Just one question, though: when you say "that's not the case with the volatile isSetupDone", do you mean it we should make `isSetupDone` `volatile`like so: `volatile boolean isSetupDone = false;`

Comment: @Christian Exactly. Sorry, it's my mistake, going to update that line. I meant `isSetupDone` to be `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore writing an element within that Object (if it is e.g. a standard HashMap, performing a put() operation on it) will not establish such a relationship. Is that correct?

Yes and no.  There is always a happens-before relationship when you read or write a `volatile` field.  The issue in your case is that even though there is a happens-before when you access the `HashMap` field, there is no memory synchronization or mutex locking when you are actually operating on the `HashMap`.  So multiple threads can see different versions of the same `HashMap` and can create a corrupted data structure depending on race conditions.

> Now, with using a volatile ConcurrentHashMap, will writing an element to it establish the happens-before relationship, i.e. will the above still work?

Typically you do *not* need to mark a `ConcurrentHashMap` as being `volatile`.  There are memory barriers that are crossed internal to the `ConcurrentHashMap` code itself.  The only time I'd use this is if the `ConcurrentHashMap` field is being changed often -- i.e. is non-final.

Your code really seems like premature optimization.  Has a profiler shown you that it is a performance problem?  I would suggest that you just synchronize on the map and me done with it.  Having two `ConcurrentHashMap` to solve this problem seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just wrote a very long comment, explaining why I think I need double-checked locking to begin with, just to realise I wasn't allowed to post anything long here. I'll get back to you in a few hours. For the time being, let me just throw the question back into the discussion: ***Is there a way to get that `ConcurrentHashMap` to use "`volatile` behaviour" when performing a `put()` on it?*** ;)

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is fully concurrent.  If you are asking if there is a happens-before relationship just by calling `setupsDone.put(...)` then the answer is yes but you don't know when the memory barrier is crossed.  You do know that one has been crossed when the put finishes.

Comment: Will that happens-before relationship/memory barrier affect just the `ConcurrentHashMap` or - as it usually does - all variables that were visible to the writing Thread before it happened? (That is, will the write to `setupsDone` affect the visibility of `o` in other threads?)

Comment: I had a look at the source code for the `ConcurrentHashMap` this weekend and tried to make sense of it. The `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java 6 has a `transient volatile` field `count` that gets apparently read by the `get()` method and written to if (and only if) a new key is added using `put()`, therefore establishing a happens-before relationship, I think. (I didn't check for "overwrites".) In Java 7, `count`is no longer declared `volatile`, but `transient volatile HashEntry<K,V>[] table;` is used instead (whose use I didn't examine in detail).